# How can I call this sub without passing in actual parameters but using the parameters it already has?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

Good afternoon everyone! I've been having difficulty being able to call a sub that has 2 parameters whenever an Option Button is updated because every other time I call this sub I pass in the parameters.

**This is the original sub that takes in 2 parameters from a Check Box after update sub which I will add below**

```
     Private Sub showCosts(HS As String, ID As Integer)
```

**One of the subs that pass in the 2 parameters to showCosts**

```
 Private Sub chkH7_AfterUpdate()
 If Me.chkH7.Value <> 0 Then
     Call showCosts("H", 7)
 Else
     Call clearValues
 End If
 End Sub
```

**The Option Button after update sub**

```
 Private Sub optInflated_AfterUpdate()
 'call the function to show the costs when the inflation toggle is updated/clicked

 Call showCosts

 End Sub
```

What I need this to do is run the sub "showCosts" again after I click the option button with the same parameters it already has. I have started to think maybe I need to incorporate a Dlookup of some sort but after beginning to do some research I found out about ByVal and now I am just all sorts of confused.

Comment: **After running** the `Sub` **does not have any parameter, anymore**... In order to use the previous parameters value, your code must keep them somehow and use the kept value next time the `Sub` is called **without parameters**. Please, try using the scenario I posted in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Please, try the next way:

1. Declare two variables on top of a standard module (in the declarations area):

```
Private prevHS As String, prevID As Integer
```

2. Adapt the existing called `Sub` to accept `Optional` parameters. Copy the next code **in the same standard module** where the above variables have been declared. Otherwise, they must be declared `As Public`:

```
Private Sub showCosts(Optional HS As String, Optional ID As Integer)
   If HS = "" Then HS = prevHS
   If ID = 0 Then ID = prevID
   prevHS = HS: prevID = ID
   'do here whatever you need...
   Debug.Print HS & " - " & ID
End Sub
```

3. Test the idea using the next `Sub`:

```
Sub testshowCosts()
   showCosts "Test", 12: Stop 'press F5 when stopped here
   showCosts
End Sub
```

You can call it with only a parameter, too, the missing one being 'taken' from variables declared on module level, using the previous used value.

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a try

Comment: @lv2424 Are you still trying? Didn't the suggested solution solve your problem?

Comment: The best angle from which to approach a problem is the **Try**-*angle*. - 
Of course it's true that *he that gives quickly gives twice* (Miguel de Cervantes), on the other hand *hair does not grow faster by being pulled* (proverb :-).

Comment: @T.M. I do not care too much about notoriety. I had a target of 20000 and now I answer only what looks to be a challenge, or the answer looks so obvious... I simple cannot understood what is to be tested so long. This page remained open, I could see his comment again and I couldn't stop myself asking... :)

Comment: Understand you deeply; no critics, just wanted to stimulate some smiling :-) @FaneDuru

Comment: @T.M. I do not have any problem. I was smiling when writing the comment in discussion, too. I mean, the one you were referring to... :)

Comment: I did try but it did not solve my issue. I am continuing to work at it today and will repost a new hopefully clearer question today

Comment: @lv2424 Can you explain here what you want, in fact? A scenario you have in mind and it is not accomplished using the above suggestion...